# What do the retOffset and retSize parameters of the CALL opcode do?

Tags: evm, opcode, eth-call

When reading the data returned by `CALL`ing another contract, `RETURNDATASIZE` and `RETURNDATACOPY` opcodes are used. They allow moving the data from an otherwise unreachable context to the memory, so it can be consumed.

The `CALL` opcode accepts parameters `retOffset` and `retSize`. According to https://www.evm.codes/ they are dealing with the same problem:

> retOffset: byte offset in the memory in bytes, where to store the return data of the sub context.
>
> retSize: byte size to copy (size of the return data).

What are these parameters used for?

Why nobody seems to be using them? It seems that everybody just passes two `0`s and then uses `RETURNDATASIZE` and `RETURNDATACOPY` to get the return data.

Are `RETURNDATASIZE` and `RETURNDATACOPY` a newer, more flexible approach? `retSize` seems difficult to work with dynamically sized data. Can `retOffset` and `retSize` still be used?

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing the question I've stumbled upon https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-211.

The `retOffset` and `retSize` approach is still working. It accepts the memory area into which the return data will be copied. If the area is too small, the data is truncated.

Nobody uses this approach anymore, because it's too inflexible. People just pass two `0`s to accept `0` bytes of return data to be copied into the memory.